# Tell Target code (convert to as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

This is the code which I used in AS2

```
on (release) {
 tellTarget ("/incorrect")
 {
  nextFrame();
 }
}
```

How do I do this in AS3 (AIR) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `tellTarget("/something")` use `(root as MovieClip).something`. Instead of `on (release) {` use `addEventListener`.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);

function buttonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    (root as MovieClip).incorrect.nextFrame();
}
```